# Why doesn't this jQuery HTML5 fallback work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  $('form').find('input[pattern],textarea[pattern]').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val().match($(this).prop('pattern'))){
      $(this).addClass('error');
    }
  });


<textarea name=... required pattern=^.{10,255}$></textarea>
```

Basically, if the value doesn't match the pattern, a class (error) is added. However, the class isn't being added to the textarea even if I only type 1-9 characters.

Comment: In HTML5 it's proper to use `data-pattern`, not `pattern`, since that's not a valid attribute. `data-*` is.

Comment: pattern is HTML5 http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute

Comment: You forgot to put the `pattern` attribute value in quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, pattern might be interpreted as a regex, but here it's just a string.  You'd need to make a regex out of it.

```
new RegExp($(this).attr('pattern'))
```

Also, you might want to throw some quotes around the attribute:

```
pattern="^.{10,255}"
```